# ObjectQuery<T>.Include() all possible references

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When using `ObjectQuery<T>.Include()` method, is there a simple way to include *all* references?

For example:

```
return _ctx.Conditions.Include("Subcondition")
                      .Include("Subcondition.Subcondition")
                      .Include("Subcondition.Subcondition.Subcondition") 
                      …
```

Where `_ctx` is a `List<Condition>` and `Subcondition` acts as a linked list of unknown length and guaranteed not to repeat or loop.

Comment: To clarify, Condition and Subcondition are both classes I created, with Condition having a reference to the head of the subcondition singly-linked list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the overwhelming flood of responses, I have concluded that this is impossible - and it seems likely that such code could very easily cause problems.  I have gotten around this by creating a recursive method that loads each subcondition one at a time and reconnects them manually. I was just hoping for a simpler way.

Comment: You could have come to the same conclusion by the overwhelming number of questions that in some form or another ask about recursive querying with LINQ to a SQL backend. The answer is always: can't be done, use CTE. Sometimes we just stop answering, I guess.